# Problem in a conditional to decide when to activate the function of each property passed to the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jsx

how are you? I'm having a problem when passing two functions (both functions make a put call in an api) as a property for the same component (I'll leave the code for them below), this component has a form but the first function (updateClientAddress) does not have all fields that the second function (updatePartnerAddress) has, so I'm trying to think of a logic to decide when to use each function, that is, when I should activate the client function or when I should activate partner.

Client.js: ***(obs: the updateAddress inside of {} is the put function that calls the api)***

```
<FormModalAddress
        onClose={() => toggleModal(false, setFormAddressShow)}
        show={formAddressShow}
        updateClientsAddressRoute={updateAddress}
        {...defaultModalProps}
/>
```

Partner.js: ***(obs: the updateAddress inside of {} is the put function that calls the api)***

```
      <FormModalAddress
        onClose={() => toggleModal(false, setFormAddressShow)}
        show={formAddressShow}
        getPartnersAddressRoute={getAddress}
        updatePartnersAddressRoute={updateAddress}
        {...defaultModalProps}
/>
```

FormModalADdress.js: ***component that receives the updateClientsAddress and updatePartnersAddress functions as props***

```
const FormModalBankInformation = ({

  updateClientsAddressRoute,
  updatePartnersAddressRoute
}) => { 
 const update = async () => {
    const address = await updatePartnersAddressRoute(id, {
      service_location_area: parseFloat(serviceLocationArea.value),
      zip_code: zipCode.value,
      city: city.value,
      district: district.value,
      state: state.value,
      street: street.value,
      street_number: parseInt(streetNumber.value),
      complement: complement.value,
    });

    console.log("ADDRESS AFTER: ", address);

  };
}
```

***OBS: Client doesnt have service_location_area field, so when i call, I need to define when to call each update (both client and partner) and when I call client I have to remove that field that does not belong to the update client.***

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FormModalAddress.js contains the component named FormModalBankInformation which does not match your other components named FormModelAddress, is this just a mistake? I'm going to assume that this is actually the FormModalAddress component you are showing.

I think you are calling the same form modal from different places, and need the same form to run a different callback depending on what is supplied to the component, is that correct?

If that's the case you could build your fields object first, and add in the service_location_area property if the updatePartnersAddressRoute function has been supplied. This assumes that you aren't supplying both functions all the time of course, either one or the other.

```js
const FormModalBankInformation = ({

  updateClientsAddressRoute,
  updatePartnersAddressRoute
}) => {
  const update = async() => {

    const fields = {
      zip_code: zipCode.value,
      city: city.value,
      district: district.value,
      state: state.value,
      street: street.value,
      street_number: parseInt(streetNumber.value),
      complement: complement.value,
    }
    '

    if (updatePartnersAddressRoute) {
      fields.service_location_area = parseFloat(serviceLocationArea.value),
    }

    const address = await updatePartnersAddressRoute(id, fields);

    console.log("ADDRESS AFTER: ", address);

  };
}
```

A cleaner way to do it might be to only have one property on the component, for example called 'updateRoute', and have an additional flag property of 'isPartner'. When isPartner === true you can add in the additional value, and then you don't need to duplicate the logic of calling the update functions, since it will call whatever function the parent component supplies. Just a thought.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the help! :D